# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException while transfering data via Bundle

Tags: android, android-bundle

Is there any workaround how to transfer larger amount of `JSON` files into another Activity?

I'm getting `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 640176 bytes`

`Activity` is taking payload of certain array of `JSONObjects` which has to be used in that `Activity`. But payload size is dynamic. Sometimes its 20 objects, sometimes 2, but currently in this case its 364 objects inside `JSONArray` and I cant pass it to `Activity`.

```
fun openStationViewer(stations: List<CityStation>){
        val int = Intent(this, CityStationMapActivity::class.java)
        val bundle = Bundle()
        val stationsJs = CityStationLoader.convertStationsToPayload(stations)
        bundle.putString(CityStationMapActivity.CITY_STATIONS, stationsJs.toString())
        int.putExtras(bundle)
        startActivityForResult(int, REQUEST_CITY_STATION_MAP)
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should not have two activities. Instead, have one activity with two fragments or composables representing the screens.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass the actual data between screens as you may run into the `TransactionTooLargeException`, which is also kinda tricky as the transaction that blows up is not necessarily the one causing issues as the size is determined by the sum of transactions leading up to the crash.

Using a statically accessed 'object' is in my opinon bad practice and a sign that the architecture is lacking.

Instead:

- Store the data in a shared Repository or similar abstraction
- Pass an id to the data in the transaction between screens
- Lookup the data in the repository using the id on the other side

Sharing the repository can be done in different ways but doing it with DI using Dagger/Hilt or Koin is a good way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a singleton object and pass it through the relevant variable. There is a 1mb limit in the bundle.

```
object Singleton {
   var singletonProp : String? = null
}

Singleton.singletonProp =syourJson
```